# I can't Toast variable value in setOnClickListener()

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, mobile-application

I want to show variable value from **imageAndTexts1.get(position).getUrl()** in setOnClickListener().

This is my code

```
public class RssReaderListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RssFeedStructure> {
    List<RssFeedStructure> imageAndTexts1 = null;

    public RssReaderListAdapter(Activity activity,
            List<RssFeedStructure> imageAndTexts) {
        super(activity, 0, imageAndTexts);
        imageAndTexts1 = imageAndTexts;


        // Permission StrictMode
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        Activity activity = (Activity) getContext();
        LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();

        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rssfeedadapter_layout, null);
        TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.feed_text);
        TextView timeFeedText = (TextView) rowView
                .findViewById(R.id.feed_updatetime);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.feed_image);
        try {

            Log.d("rssfeed", "imageAndTexts1.get(position).getImgLink() :: "
                    + imageAndTexts1.get(position).getImgLink() + " :: "
                    + imageAndTexts1.get(position).getTitle()+ " :: "
                    + imageAndTexts1.get(position).getUrl());
            textView.setText(imageAndTexts1.get(position).getTitle());
            SpannableString content = new SpannableString(imageAndTexts1.get(
                    position).getPubDate());
            content.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 0, 13, 0);

            timeFeedText.setText(content);

             textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    private Activity context;

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), imageAndTexts1.get(position).getUrl().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


               /*          String url = imageAndTexts1.get(position).getUrl().toString();
                         Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                         i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                         context.startActivity(i); */
                    }
                });
```

when I run this code it can show text from Log.d(). But when I click textView in Emulator it show error like this.

```
07-02 09:49:10.844: E/AndroidRuntime(968): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-02 09:49:10.844: E/AndroidRuntime(968): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-02 09:49:10.844: E/AndroidRuntime(968):  at com.amit.adapter.RssReaderListAdapter$1.onClick(RssReaderListAdapter.java:84)
07-02 09:49:10.844: E/AndroidRuntime(968):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
07-02 09:49:10.844: E/AndroidRuntime(968):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
07-02 09:49:10.844: E/AndroidRuntime(968):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
07-02 09:49:10.844: E/AndroidRuntime(968):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-02 09:49:10.844: E/AndroidRuntime(968):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-02 09:49:10.844: E/AndroidRuntime(968):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
07-02 09:49:10.844: E/AndroidRuntime(968):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-02 09:49:10.844: E/AndroidRuntime(968):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-02 09:49:10.844: E/AndroidRuntime(968):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
07-02 09:49:10.844: E/AndroidRuntime(968):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
07-02 09:49:10.844: E/AndroidRuntime(968):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

In log.d() it can show text without error. But in setOnClickListener() when I click text in list it show NullPointerException. please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `context`, which is going to be `null` at this point since you don't assign to it.

You should be able to use `activity` from the `getview` method. i.e replace `context` in your listener with `activity`.

Answer (score 2):

```
private Activity context;
```

is your problem, that is already `null`.

Use instead `YourActivityName.this` inside your `Toast`.

Answer (score 0):

`Activity testActivity;` add this line below  `List<RssFeedStructure> imageAndTexts1 = null;`

then initialize this in your constructor.

```
 public RssReaderListAdapter(Activity activity,
            List<RssFeedStructure> imageAndTexts) {
        super(activity, 0, imageAndTexts);
        imageAndTexts1 = imageAndTexts;
        testActivity=activity; // Newly added

        // Permission StrictMode
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }
    }
Now you can use the Toast message like this,


Toast.makeText(testActivity, imageAndTexts1.get(position).getUrl().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code.

```
    Toast.makeText(ActivityName.this, ""+imageAndTexts1.get(position).getUrl().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

first Change is ActivityName.this

and second is :   ""+imageAndTexts1.get(position).getUrl().toString()

Answer (score 0):

problem in ur code is   u r using getActivityContext() which cause problem sometimes... instead use

```
     Toast.makeText(UrActivity.this; "UrlValue is" + imageAndTexts1.get(position).getUrl(), 3000).show();
```